# Query for date using C# mongodb driver when date is a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to get all records with date in certain range.
Unfortunately dates are stored as strings.
I wanted to do something like this

```
from r in collection.AsQueryable()
         .where(toDate(r.Date) > toDate(startDate) && toDate(r.Date) < toDate(endDate))
         .select r;
```

Where toDate() is my method, which converts string into DateTime using ParseExact. But that is not allowed since I cannot use methods in a query.

Comment: What you mean that you are not allowed? Have you tried using `DateTime.ParseExact` What happened?

Comment: And I think you should also decide if you are using query syntax or method syntax...

Comment: @GiladGreen I'm getting "System.InvalidOperationException - (Statistics2.Models.MongoConnectorModel).toDate({document}{Date}) is not supported."

Comment: Did you ever get this worked?

Comment: @HaBo No, we ended up changing data field to DateTime format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to filter through date column which is stored as string in Mongo DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55508771/unable-to-filter-through-date-column-which-is-stored-as-string-in-mongo-db)