# Unable to filter through date column which is stored as string in Mongo DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have a application which writes data into MONGODB.
In the document, I have a field called UpdatedOn. In this I'm writing datetime in string format like below:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

I know I should have used date type only,this is being stored as string in the database now.
Now I got a requirement to filter data based on this field between 2 dates.
Say something like this :
Start Date : "01/01/2019"
End Date : "31/01/2019"

This is the code , I have used below (which is not working)

```
IMongoCollection<Order> OrderCollection = GetOrderCollection();
List<OrderFilter> lstJobs;

FilterDefinitionBuilder<Order> OrderFilter = Builders<Order>.Filter;

DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2019");   
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime("31/01/2019");

var filter = OrderFilter.Gte("UpdatedOn", start) &
OrderFilter.Lt("UpdatedOn", end);

var fields = Builders<Order>.Projection.Include(p => p.Id);
lstOrders = await OrderCollection.Find(filter).Project<OrderFilter>(fields).ToListAsync<OrderFilter>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

OrderFilter class:

```
public class OrderFilter
{    
   [DataMember(Name = "id")]
   public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Order class:

```
public class Order
{
   [DataMember(Name = "id")]
   public string Id { get; set; }

   [DataMember(Name = "UpdatedOn")]
   public string UpdatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Since UpdatedOn is string and already some data has been inserted. It is not practicle to change it.
Can anyone help me to filter in this case. Is there any typecasting or conversions I can do in the code itself and do the filtering.
Many thanks!

Comment: to begin, change `DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2019");` to `DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime("2019/01/01")` to avoid the day-month ambiguity

Comment: @JohnB I did. It didn't help though

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to parse the string to Date to be able to compare other Dates to it.
See [the docs here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/).

To be able to do this in C# you'll have to use the Aggregate method like this:

```
DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2019");   
DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime("31/01/2019");

var projectionDefinition = 
Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("convertedDate");

OrderCollection.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>("{ $addFields: {convertedDate: { $toDate: '$UpdatedOn' }}}").Match(
    Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte(x => x["convertedDate"], new BsonDateTime(start))
    & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Lte(x => x["convertedDate"], new BsonDateTime(end)))
    .Project(projectionDefinition).As<Order>();
```

You'll probably be able to make this a lot prettier by using stages.

For example,

```
var projectionDefinition = Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.Exclude("convertedDate");
var expression = new BsonDocument(new List<BsonElement>
{
    new BsonElement("convertedDate", new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$toDate", "$UpdatedOn")))
});

var addFieldsStage = new BsonDocument(new BsonElement("$addFields", expression));

var gteFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte(x => x["convertedDate"], new BsonDateTime(startDate));
var lteFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Lte(x => x["convertedDate"], new BsonDateTime(endDate));

var combinedFilter= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And(gteFilter, lteFilter);

var result = coll.Aggregate().AppendStage<BsonDocument>(addFieldsStage).Match(combinedFilter).Project(projectionDefinition).As<Order>();
```

And if you add         `[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]` above your class you'll be able to drop the projection stage.

Or in your case probably just replace it with the projection you are currently using and setting the `.As<Type>` accordingly.